# Replace each character of regex match by a another character

Tags: javascript

If I have this string: `foo bar baz qux bar quux quuz`, I would like to replace each character of `bar` by `X` (`foo XXX baz qux XXX quux quuz`).

Maybe `.replace()` can be used in such a way? Obviously a `"foo bar baz qux bar quux quuz".replace(/bar/g, "X")` wouldn't be enough since it would return `foo X baz qux X quux quuz` instead of `foo XXX baz qux XXX quux quuz`.

This is just an example, but I need to use regex. I can't do something like this:

```js
"foo bar baz qux bar quux quuz"
  .split(" ")
  .map(x => x === "bar" ? "X".repeat(x.length) : x)
  .join(" ")
```

I need the `bar` to be found by a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to generate the replacement:

```js
"foo bar baz qux bar quux quuz".replace(/bar/g, m => "X".repeat(m.length))
```